# Is there any way to continue a powershell script as a normal powershell window?

Tags: powershell

I'm not quite sure how to word this, but what I'm trying to do is create a powershell script that enters a pssession on a computer I frequently have to connect to and then turns it into the normal powershell interface so I can enter commands. I've had to type out the Enter-PSSession command at least a thousand times by now, so I'm wondering if there's any way to slap it into a script so that I'll just have to type in the credential password and it'll just switch into the normal interface. Thanks in advance to anyone that can help.

Answer (score 0):

well, you could use your [powershell profile](http://www.howtogeek.com/50236/customizing-your-powershell-profile/) for that, just create `new-pssession` when you load your powershell and you can enter it afterwards.

So you will add something like this to your profile:

```
$session = New-PSSession computername -Credentials (Get-Credentials -UserName domain\username)
```

And when your PS loads you can just do `enter-pssession $session`